# PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase vs PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase ?? i am very confused as to which one to use

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase vs PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase ...
Which one to use and why ?

> https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php

All the functions and methods defined here are under PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase.
SO why to use PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase ?? and what is the difference and where is the API for it. ?? i am very confused about it.

**WHERE ARE ALL THE ASSERTIONS FOR IT ????**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` and `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` is version of supported Selenium server.

`PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` supports so called Selenium RC server. API is [here](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.1/en/selenium.html#selenium.seleniumtestcase).
`PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` supports Selenium 2 Server.

Selenium 2 uses WebDrivers:

> Selenium 1.0 + WebDriver = Selenium 2.0
>
> - WebDriver is designed in a simpler and more concise programming    interface along with addressing some limitations in the Selenium-RC
>     API.
> - WebDriver is a compact Object Oriented API when compared to Selenium1.0
> - It drives the browser much more effectively and over comes the limitations of Selenium 1.x which affected our functional test
>     coverage, like the file upload or download, pop-ups and dialogs
>     barrier
> - WebDriver overcomes the limitation of Selenium Rc's Single Host origin policy

One of the reasons to use Selenium RC is `Selenium IDE` with PHP Formatter. It is tool for recording tests from browser, but with Selenium2 you can use more browsers for testing, for example, `PhantomJS`.

Comment: yeah. but now the important part is this: When I use PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase  I do have some ready made methods which i find over here : https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php  but when i want to use click function, byId function than i need to extend the PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase but than the previous methods are not valid for this class.so wher is d API for PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase ?? i cannot use the methods which i used for PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase in PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase

Comment: And also which one has better apis and which one has to be used ???? i m scratching my head since long for the same issue.

Comment: `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` is better, because first version was designed for old Selenium RC. But `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` is under development. You needn't use `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` for tests written for `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase`. Also you can click by id: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php#L143

Comment: ok so in short i should follow these commands in my project : http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/selenium.html#selenium.selenium2testcase.examples.WebTest.php instead of http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/selenium.html#selenium.seleniumtestcase.examples.WebTest.php   ???  so is it the case that the website in misguiding us or a proper information is not given for the new users like me ??

Comment: Yes. This http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/selenium.html#selenium.selenium2testcase.examples.WebTest.php is basic structure for you test. And you know about API examples, I mean [tests](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php) There is no proper information. If you want to use WebDrivers, you should use `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase`: _The PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase test case lets you use the WebDriver API (partially implemented)._